LM2917 frequency to voltage converter doesn't work when the 470 Ω resistor is connected to the Zener diode
I'm building a frequency to voltage converter based on the schematics available for the LM2917N, but I'm having some trouble when I get to test it. I've done the simulation on LTspice and it works fine, but when testing in a lab a few issues emerged. First the IC gets very hot if there is no 470 Ω resistor for the Zener diode, and a residual voltage appears even without input frequency, about 40 mV.
For the intended use I do need the resistor at pin 9, given the circuit will use a 12 V battery as supply, but when I test it with the 470 Ω resistor at pin 9 the circuit stops working and the resistor itself gets hot instead of the IC.
Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?
*the opamp in the schematics is just to simulate the wave form of the input.


"First IC gets verry hot if there is no 470ohms resistor for the zener diode"  you may have destroyed the Zener if you connected pin 9 directly to 12 V.  "but when i test it with the 470 ohms resistor at pin 9 the circuit stop working and the resistor it self get hot instead of the IC." This would be consistent with the zener being toast.

The datasheet for the LM2917N could have been clearer. However, there is a line in the Absolute Maximum Ratings that says

Supply current (Zener options) 25 mA

My reading of this, is that you should never allow 25 mA or more current through pin 9.
Under the table "Electrical Characteristics", it lists the Zener regulator voltage as 7.56 V (with a 470 \$\Omega\$ drop resistor.
My conclusion is that if one connects 12 V directly to pin 9 of an LM2917N, one will likely cause permanent damage to the Zener regulator, and perhaps other parts of the IC as well.
Also, be sure to properly size the 470 \$\Omega\$ resistor. If you use a nominal 12 V battery, charged to 13.8V, there will be 13.8 -  7.56 (the Zener voltage) or 6.24 V across the resistor. It should then dissipate 83 mW. However, if you power the chip with a higher voltage, with the full max 25 mA flowing through it, the power dissipated will be.
\$470\times0.025\times0.025 = 294 \text{ mW}\$
Therefore, in that case, one should use, at a minimum, a 1/2 W resistor.

this makes sense, I first tried the Minimum Component Tachometer Diagram, but using the Lm2917n because I had no luck finding the lm2907, only after reading a little more of the datasheet did I understood the function of the zener on pin 9. Now I see that it was the mistake thank you very much.

@GustavoFalcomer after returning to this Q and A, it occurs to me that the heating of the 470 $\Omega$ resistor may not be a sign of a burnt IC if the resistor is sized too small. Just something else to consider.
